# Occurring only in one environment Invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: db2

I stumbled with this error since long time which is occurring only in one of our environments which is connecting to db2 data base and our appserver is websphere7
invalid operation: result set is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null.

Can any one help me why this is exception is occurring only in one environment besides having the same code in all environments?

Your kind help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We would need more context about this issue.

Comment: You could start with comparing the JDBC connection pool settings in WAS.

Comment: I have compared connection pool settings in WAS of all environments which are same . Besides compared the size of db2jcc4.jar in server lib. No issues with the size as well.